# Not recieving data python socktes

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server

I am creating a simple chat room server using python and when I send data using I'm not receiving it. The code worked until I sepperated it using functions and classes. I did this so it would be simpler to add a UI

here's my server side code:

```py
import socket
import select
from tkinter import *
import threading

HEADER_LENGTH = 10
IP = socket.gethostbyname('0.0.0.0')
PORT = 1234

class ServerNoGui():

    def __init__(self):
        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        self.server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
        self.server_socket.listen()

        self.sockets_list = [self.server_socket]

        self.clients = {}

        print("server started")
        print("Starting thread sub-proccesses...")
        acceptLoop = threading.Thread(target=self.acceptUsers)
        acceptLoop.start()
        recieveLoop = threading.Thread(target=self.manageDataSending)
        recieveLoop.start()
        print("sub-proccesses started!")


    def recieve_message(self, client_socket):
        message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

        if not len(message_header):
            return False

        message_length = int(float(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip()))
        return {'header': message_header, 'data': client_socket.recv(message_length)}

    def acceptUsers(self):
        read_sockets, _x_, exception_sockets = select.select(self.sockets_list, [], self.sockets_list) 

        for notified_socket in read_sockets:
            if notified_socket == self.server_socket:
                client_socket, client_address = self.server_socket.accept()
                print("accepted")

                user = self.recieve_message(client_socket)

                #print(user)
                print("Recieved")

                if(not user):
                    continue

                self.sockets_list.append(client_socket)
                print("added to list")

                self.clients[client_socket] = user
                print("created user")

                print(f"Accepted connection from {client_address[0]}{client_address[1]} username: {user['data'].decode('utf-8')}")

    def manageDataSending(self):
        while True:
            read_sockets, _x_, exception_sockets = select.select(self.sockets_list, [], self.sockets_list)  
            print("point")
            for notified_socket in read_sockets:
                if notified_socket == self.server_socket:
                    print("point 0")
                    self.acceptUsers()
                else:
                    print("point 1")
                    message = self.recieve_message(notified_socket)

                    if(message is False):
                        print(f"Closed connection from {self.clients[notified_socket]['data'].decode('utf-8')}")
                        self.sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)
                        del self.clients[notified_socket]
                        continue

                    else:
                        user = self.clients[notified_socket]

                        type_, data = message['data'].decode("utf-8").split("$")


                        if(type_ == "message"):
                            print(f"Recieved Message from {user['data'].decode('utf-8')} : {message['data'].decode('utf-8')} of type {type_}")
                            for client_socket in self.clients:

                                if client_socket != notified_socket:
                                    client_socket.send(user['header'] + user['data'] + message['header'] + message['data'])

            for notified_socket in exception_sockets:
                sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)
                del clients[notified_socket]    
                print(f"Closed connection from {clients[notified_socket]['data'].decode('utf-8')}")

class serverGUI():
    def __init__():
        window = Tk()
        window.title(f"Chatt.py HOSTING SERVER (IP : {IP} \\\\ HOST : {HOST})")

    def createWidgets(self):
        return False

    def log(self, data):
        return False

    def loop(self):
        window.mainloop()



serverBackend = ServerNoGui()
```

and here's the client

```py
import socket
import select
import errno
import sys


HEADER_LENGTH = 10

IP = socket.gethostbyname("0.0.0.0")#'192.168.0.40' 
PORT = 1234

my_username = input("Username: ")
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))
client_socket.setblocking(False)

username = my_username.encode("utf-8");
username_header = f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode("utf-8")

client_socket.send(username_header + username)

while True:
    messageInput = input(f"Me({my_username}) > ")
    message = f"message${messageInput}"

    if(message):
        message = message.encode("utf-8")
        message_header = f"{len(message):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode("utf-8")
        client_socket.send(message_header + message)
        print(f"sent {message_header} : {message}")

    try:
        while True:
            username_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            if(not len(username_header)):
                print("connection closed by server")
                sys.exit()
            username_lenght = int(username_header.decode("utf-8").strip())

            username = client_socket.recv(username_lenght).decode("utf-8")

            message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            message_length = int(message_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
            messageRaw = client_socket.recv(message_length).decode("utf-8")
            type_, message = messageRaw.split("$")
            if(type_ == message):
                print(f"{username} >> {message}")

    except IOError as e:
        if(e.errno != errno.EAGAIN and e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK):
            print("READ ERR",str(e))
            sys.exit()
        continue

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error".str(e))
        sys.exit()
```

I decided to try with two clients I get the following output
Server:

```
server started
Starting thread sub-proccesses...
sub-proccesses started!
point
point 0
accepted
Recieved
added to list
created user
Accepted connection from 127.0.0.160338 username: test1
point
point 0
accepted
Recieved
added to list
created user
Accepted connection from 127.0.0.160340 username: test2
point
point 1
Recieved Message from test2 : message$hello of type message
point
point 1
Recieved Message from test1 : message$ of type message
point
point 1
Recieved Message from test1 : message$hello of type message
```

client1:

```
Username: test1
Me(test1) > 
sent b'8         ' : b'message$'
Me(test1) > hello
sent b'13        ' : b'message$hello'
```

client2:

```
Username: test2
Me(test2) > hello
sent b'13        ' : b'message$hello'
```

as you can see the messages are sent and recieved by the server but not displayed (I'm not stupid I hit enter a few times).

Answer (score 0):

Your server code is confusing and probably not doing what you thought. First you create a thread to accept connections giving it `acceptUsers` as its thread function (call this thread **A**). However, that function will only run once *in that thread*, then it will exit after it has visited all of the `read_sockets` (because there's no `while True` loop).

Second, your other thread (**B**) is running in `manageDataSending` -- also executing `select`, but when a client connects, it's *calling* `acceptUsers`. That means on the first connection to your server, there's a "race" between the two threads. It's questionable what will happen next because both are now destined to execute the `acceptUsers` code at more or less the same time, so the exact order of operations in the two threads is now indeterminate.

It's possible that thread **A** could run first, handle the `server_socket` (accept the connection *and* do the receive) and quit, before thread **B** enters the `select` call in `acceptUsers`. That would leave thread **B** waiting in the `select` (in `acceptUsers`) until the next time a client connects or sends data.

On the other hand, it's possible that thread **A** and thread **B** both get past the `select` in `acceptUsers` and both execute the `accept` call. Then the `accept` will succeed in one, and block in the other, waiting for a subsequent incoming connection. In either case, your thread **B** eventually ends up blocked in a place in your code that you didn't expect it to be.

Bottom line: there's no obvious reason for you to have the two separate threads, both doing a `select` call. It will be much simpler and easier to understand what is going on if create only one thread, and have it execute your socket `select` in one place, have that place handle the socket notifications for both incoming connections and incoming client data.

One other thing to note: you don't really need to handle the `exception_sockets` separately. If one of your clients goes away, its entry in the `read_sockets` list will be signaled as "ready-to-read" and when you attempt to read it, you will get an end-of-file indication (i.e. zero-length buffer returned).

Comment: Thank you so much I'm clearly very new to threading I figured it out but I was confused why it worked so this was super helpful and that note helped to make the code more efficient. I was up all night trying to fix that bug so thank you!